Files overwriting messagebox in a loop using VBA
I have a working script that saves multiple Solidworks parts through a loop using vba. The amount and name of parts is dependent on the user that selects parts to be saved in a userform.
If files are already saved in the folder with the same name, a messagebox pops up with a Do you want to overwrite this file questions with either yes (overwrites the file) and no (cancels and goes back to subform). The yes options works fine. However, when I select no, the entire statement cancels. Therefore it is never an option to NOT overwrite part1 and to DO overwrite part2, because the messagebox for part2 never occurs. How can I make this happen? Hopefully this image clears out my problem. You can also find my accessory code below.

If you have any further questions, or I need to clarify something more, please let me know.
    'Save the file if it does not exist yet
    Dim FileNameOverwrite
    If Not Dir(finalName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        FileNameOverwrite = MsgBox("Filename " & finalNameCut & " already exists. Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "File overwrite")
        UserParam.Hide
        If FileNameOverwrite = vbNo Then
            UserParam.Show
            Exit Sub ' Stop the code execution, no more looping
        End If
    End If
     
    swModelToExport.Extension.SaveAs3 finalName, 0, 1, Nothing, Nothing, nErrors, nWarnings
     
    'Reopen assembly
    Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(PathInit, 1, 0, "", nStatus, nWarnings)                                                'Open the model
    Set swModelActivated = swApp.ActivateDoc3(PathInit, False, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swUserDecision, nErrors)         'Activate the model
    Set swModelToExport = swApp.ActiveDoc                                                                                 'Get the activated model
Next
    
End Sub

EDIT


Have a look my comment on code line Exit Sub . You just need to remove it.

Thank you, but it still does not proceed to a second msgbox

Implement a Boolean to Decide Whether to Save a File

It is assumed that you want to save the file when it doesn't exist, and if it exists, when the user selects Yes in the message box.
Sorry, I don't know SolidWorks so I used only the lines I'm familiar with.

For...

    ' ... !?

    'Save the file if it does not exist yet
    
    Dim FileNameOverwrite
    Dim IsToBeSaved

    IsToBeSaved = True
    
    If Not Dir(finalName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        FileNameOverwrite = MsgBox("Filename " & finalNameCut _
            & " already exists. Do you want to overwrite?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "File overwrite")
        UserParam.Hide
        If FileNameOverwrite = vbNo Then
            UserParam.Show
            IsToBeSaved = False
        End If
    End If
     
    If IsToBeSaved Then
        ' your 'SaveAs' line
    
    End If
     
    'Reopen assembly
    
    ' the last 3 lines
     
Next


Additional comment that @JetskiS may want to consider: changing the MessageBox from vbYesNo to vbYesNoCancel, and leaving the old "exit back to subform" functionality attached to the new vbCancel option instead of the vbNo option

@VBasic2008 Thank you, it works better now but still not as I exactly want it. Now, after selecting no in the first msgbox (saving part1), the msgbox disappears and goes back to my userform again. Only if I close the userform, the next overwrite msgbox for part4 pops up. Now, I want the second messagebox to appear as soon as I select no on the first msgbox (part1). So that the user can determine if the file must be overwritten (up to eight parts). For clarification purposes, I included a figure in my post: Red is how it works at the moment and orange is how I want it to work.
